# Dummy variables, interaction terms and panel data fixed-effects model

Tags: categorical-data, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am interested in incorporating time-invariant variables to a fixed-effects panel data model.  As we know, the coefficient corresponding to the time-invariant variable will be dropped, because of the fixed-effects specification.  Regarding this, I am aware that we can overcome this problem by using the **interaction** of a year dummy (time fixed effect) and the time-invariant variable (please see [How to keep time invariant variables in a fixed effects model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90754/how-to-keep-time-invariant-variables-in-a-fixed-effects-model)).  My question is that if it would be correct to include only the interacted term(s) *without* the time (year) dummy? Many thanks in advance!